# Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Table of contents does not show the list of Tables, Figures, List of Acronyms and Acknowledgements etc. But it starts with Chapter 1. How I can include them in Table of Contents. Instead of contents, I want Table of Contents.

A minimum working example is given below:

```
      \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
      \usepackage{titlesec}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[english]{babel}
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
      \setlength\parindent{24pt}
      \usepackage{titlesec}
      \usepackage{acro}
      \usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
      \begin{document}
          \author{Ahmed Arif}
      \title{Title of Thesis is Research}
      \date{November 2016}

      \frontmatter
      \maketitle
      \tableofcontents
      \listoftables
      \listoffigures
      \printacronyms[name= List of Acronyms,sort=true,heading=chapter*]
      \mainmatter
      \chapter{Introduction}
      This is introduction chapter. 

      \section{Section 1}
      This is a section. 

      \chapter{Literature}
      Literature review is performed in this chapter. 

      \end{document}
```

Comment: I think that you must compile twice.

Comment: Compiling twice does not solve anything. It only works in case of referencing.